# What links Lily Briscoe's desire in To The Lighthouse to the desire of the old man in Slave Old Man?

Tags: character-analysis, virginia-woolf, to-the-lighthouse, slave-old-man, patrick-chamoiseau

The two books being compared are *To The Lighthouse* by Virginia Woolf and *Slave Old Man* (or *The Old Slave and the Mastiff*) by Patrick Chamoiseau. I have to write a thesis but am having a hard time finding the common link between the desires of the main characters.

Lily Briscoe desires to be an artist in a time where the social norm is for women to be married and caretakers of the family. The Old Man desires to connect with his past life, before slavery, and does so through the woods he escapes into.

I need help in unifying these two separate works into a single idea.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. This sounds like an interesting question, but you need a lot of luck to find someone here who happens to have read both books or who can read them fast enough to help you. In the mean time, try to find other ways of looking at the desires of both characters. Try questions such as 'What triggers those desires?', 'Where does it lead them?', 'How does it change them?' etc. Try to think of different perspectives until you find something that you can use as a starting point.

Comment: Desire for freedom from shackles of society, a desire to be yourself? Dunno.

Comment: To whoever wants to close-vote this question: I think close-votes here require a better justification than just claiming that the question is opinion-based. I.e. to explain why this would be more opinion-based than [tag:interpretation] questions, which are accepted on this site.